# Add Edit Text in a Menu item in Action Bar in Android Studio

Tags: android

I need to add a Edit Text with a Title in Menu Item?

I have created the menu with the item  title Decimal Place .
But I want to add a edit text to enter the decimal place in that item.
Or Display a custom dialog  with a text box to enter the decimal place

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to add the `EditText` to the XML for your ToolBar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

      <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
         android:background="#000000" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```